# Check when component is removed from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable that holds several JPanels using a custom renderer/editor. The JPanel listens to another object for changes. Now when I remove the rows from the JTable the JPanel still exists in the listener list in the object so the JPanel doesn't get destroyed.

Previously I displayed the JPanel in another JPanel so when the object got removed I could add some code to unregister the listener in its removeNotify() method.

The removeNotify() trick doesn't work when the JPanel is in a JTable because it is constantly removed and re-added to the table's renderer/editor. I tried using addNotify() to add the JPanel as a listener, but somehow it doesn't get removed from the listener list.
So how can I do this as clean as possible?

How I add rows to the table:

```
public void fillTable()
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel(getSomeObject());
    model.addRow(new Object[]{panel});
}
```

How the custom panel registers as a listener:

```
public class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements CustomObjectListener
{
    public CustomPanel(CustomObjet obj)
    {
        obj.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void CustomObjectEvent(Event evt)
    {
        handle event;
    }
}
```

How the event is thrown:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    ArrayList<CustomObjectListener> listeners = new ArrayList<CustomObjectListener>();

    public CustomObject()
    {
    }

    public void addListener(CustomObjectListener listener)
    {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(CustomObjectListener listener)
    {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void fireEvent(Event evt)
    {
        for (CustomObjectListener listener : listeners)
        {
            listener.CustomObjectEvent(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont add _components_ to the model. Instead, add _data_ which is rendered/edited by custom cellRenderers/-Editors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new TableModel and overriding the setRowCount() method.

```
public class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
{
    @Override
    public void setRowCount(int rowCount)
    {
        if (rowCount < getRowCount())
        {
            for (int i = getRowCount()-1; i >= rowCount; i--)
            {
                ((CustomPanel)getValueAt(i, 0)).removeListeners();
            }
        }
        super.setRowCount(rowCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: again: do not mix data and view realm! Do not store the CustomPanel in the model. Instead store the CustomObject, make the model listen to (property or custom, doesn't matter) changes of the object and fire tableModelEvents as appropriate.

Comment: While reading this comment it gave me some kind of wake-up-call. I'll make adjustments accordingly but won't post them as it isn't really related to the question asked.

Comment: For the record and mainly others who might view this post: I've made a custom TableCellRenderer/Editor which extends from the CustomPanel. It takes a CustomObject from the table model and displays it. This gave things a massive performance boost! Things load super fast now and I can recommend this to everyone. Thanks kleopatra ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a JTable that holds several JPanels using a custom renderer/editor.

The `DefaultCellEditor` has a `stopCellEditing()` method you should be able to add your code to.

Or maybe you can add a PropertyChangeListener to the table:

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
{
    //  A cell has started/stopped editing

    if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
    {
        if (table.isEditing())
            processEditingStarted();
        else
            processEditingStopped();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, when a JPanel is removed from the JTable the JPanel needs to remove itself from the object's listener list. This way there are no references left to the JPanel and the GC can collect the JPanel.

Comment: Then your CustomPanel that you use as the editor needs to keep a reference to the CustomObject. When stopCellEditing() is invoked, then you can remove the listeners.